# How to show database content in tab Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview, tabactivity

Hi i have Tab activity(Chapter,subject) and database. i need to show the chapter_table
content into (chapter)tabview and subject_table content into (subject)tab view.
I use one activity for both this tabview. my question is that how to show content of  database  in tabview. It's not possible to Use listActivity with tab activity.
How i do that? is any other way to show the content of db in tabactivity?.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to have a `ListActivity` to use a `ListView` -- you can include a `ListView` in any layout you wish.

Comment: but how to add listview in tabActivity(not xml but in java)

Comment: I just assumed you were using XML for your layouts but you can create a `ListView` programmatically as well. I don't recommend doing it this way, but it can be done.

Comment: means it's possible to create listview programmatically and then assign database content which will show on tabactivity?

Comment: it is possible to create the `ListView` programmatically in whatever activity you like, and use that as the content for your `TabActivity`